# How to create a view like this in Java-fx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm having some problems with this view. What I need to do it in JavaFX to add this 'border' and divide the circle into 2 parts.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

Circle mycircle = new Circle(200,200,200);
mycircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setCenter(mycircle);

}
```

I don't have errors but it's not the view what I am looking for. So can anyone help me with this, please

[image]

And btw sorry for bad image quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this satisfy your needs?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HalfCircleDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Group circleGroup = new Group();

        Circle greenCircle = new Circle(200,200,200);
        greenCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        Circle blueCircle = new Circle(200,200,200);
        blueCircle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(400, 200);
        greenCircle.setClip(clip);

        circleGroup.getChildren().setAll(blueCircle, greenCircle);

        root.setCenter(circleGroup);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Path`s](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html) with [`ArcTo`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/ArcTo.html) elements:

```
private static Group createHalfCircles(double radius) {
    Path upperHalf = new Path(
            new MoveTo(0, radius),
            new ArcTo(radius, radius, 0, 2*radius, radius, true, false),
            new ClosePath());
    upperHalf.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
    upperHalf.setStroke(null);

    Path lowerHalf = new Path(
            new MoveTo(2 * radius, radius),
            new ArcTo(radius, radius, 0, 0, radius, true, false),
            new ClosePath());
    lowerHalf.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    lowerHalf.setStroke(null);

    return new Group(upperHalf, lowerHalf);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Scene scene = new Scene(createHalfCircles(50));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```